# How to see the query string of an NSPredicate or an NSFetchRequest?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is it possible to see the completed query string, with all the variables substituted to their actual values? Would be good for debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turn on Core Data debug and you will see the raw sql calls.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html

Comment: Link is broken.  This looks like a good solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging

Answer (score 2):

You could just log the predicate with NSLog(@"%@", predicate). Most values will show directly, except those that are cast e.g. dates or bool. For those you will have to log the variable separately.