# How to log CoreData SQL queries?

Tags: sql, ios, core-data, logging

I was wondering if there is an option to log SQL queries in CoreData?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yep, you may do that by putting `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to "Arguments Passed On Launch"

Comment: If anyone's wondering where you should set this, select Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments tab.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that you can also get sql file out of your Documents folder. Open Terminal and paste this line in (replace values in slash-brackets with yours):

```
/Users/<YourUsername>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SimulatorVersion>/Applications/<AppID>/Documents/<SQLDBName>.sqlite
```

Just open file in your favorite SQL query browser.