# CoreData performFetch in viewDidLoad not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When my main view controller is loaded and it calls `viewDidLoad` I am performing a fetch request and retiring an array or my core data objects:

```
+ (NSArray *)getData {

    // Fetch Data
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[[AppDelegate instance] fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    NSArray *items = [[AppDelegate instance].fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    return items;

}//end
```

For some reason, this returns an empty array when called from `viewDidLoad`.

If I call the same method from `viewDidAppear:` it works correctly and returns the `NSArray` of my `CoreData` objects.

Is there a reason why this won't work in `viewDidLoad`?

**EDIT:**

Fetched Results Controller method:

```
/**
 * The controller the gets our results from core data
 *
 * @version $Revision: 0.1
 */
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create and configure a fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SiteConfig" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // Create the sort descriptors array
    NSSortDescriptor *sectionTitle = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sectionTitle, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // Memory management

    return fetchedResultsController;

}//end
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your view controller is part of your MainWindow.xib, and so its viewDidLoad is being called before your app delegate gets the core data context ready.

You probably want to run this in viewWillAppear anyway, so that you'll get new data if you leave the screen and return. The other option would be to ensure the app delegate responds to fetchedResultsController by getting the core data stack ready if it isn't already.

Comment: I would rather have my app delegate get it ready. Should I do something in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to prepare the `fetchedResultsController`?

Comment: I believe, and you can confirm, that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called after `viewDidLoad` of your view controller. How are you preparing the fetchedResultsController now?

Comment: I updated my question with the `fetchedResultsController` code.

Comment: Hrm. Assuming you're using the managedObjectContext method from Apple's Core Data project template, that looks OK. Are you doing any other setup in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: that coudl affect this? Or in any other view controller's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods? You might also try [enabling SQL debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging) to see why your fetch isn't returning results.

Comment: Yeah, not doing anything strange. At what point am I suppose to do a fetch?  Doesn't my `getData` method handle that?  Confused why the fetch wouldn't return anything...

Comment: I'm also at a bit of a loss. I would think it makes more sense to do the fetch in viewWillAppear, but I really don't see any reason from the code you've shown that it wouldn't work in viewDidLoad. Does it actually return an empty array? Or nil? If it returns nil, what else is nil? The fetchedResultsController itself, for example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13430/discussion-between-nic-hubbard-and-jesse-rusak)