# How to print Core Data debug values?

Tags: ios, sqlite, debugging, core-data

How can I print the values being sent to the sqlite database while using Core Data SQL Debug?

Using the  "**-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1**" in my "**Arguments Passed on Launch**" debug options prints the SQL structure just fine

(you can check see how to use this here: [XCode4 and Core Data: How to enable SQL Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging))

But the problem is that the NSLog printed is something like `UPDATE ZTABLE SET ZCOLUMN = ? WHERE ZID = ?` and it does not help at all if you are trying to see what is the full SQL statement and/or data being sent to the database.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open "Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme..." in Xcode and add
to "Arguments Passed on Launch":

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
```

(The second launch argument is needed for Core Data debugging on
iOS 10/macOS 10.12 or later, see [com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431407/com-apple-coredata-sqldebug-not-working) for more information.)

The you'll see all the values that the SQL statements are bound to.
Example output:

```
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZEVENT(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZTIMESTAMP) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)13
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)1
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = "368650709.435904"
test56[1588:c07] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

Comment: It is not showing `NSFetchRequest` please let me know is there any way to show that also

Comment: @VarunNaharia: You can simply print the request, something like `NSLog(@"request: %@", request)`

Comment: I am using swift and I checked `po fetchRequest` on console and I got this `<NSFetchRequest: 0x1704c23e0> (entity: TravelDetail; predicate: (id == 6412); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )`

Comment: @VarunNaharia: In Swift you can do  `print("request:", request)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xcode 8, you will need to also need to add additional argument

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
```