# fetch with predicate always return nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities, one is "Object" another is "Logo", and they have got a relationship one to one. When i am adding some Logo to core data i want to check if my Object already has one. So I making predicate and fetch with it. But my result is always 0, so there is no such Logos with logo.object.id == id.

I am sure that they are there, so I am not sure about this code. Maybe predicate is wrong? Can you give some advice?

```
class func fetchLogoWithId(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, id: Int64) -> Logo? {
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Logo")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "object.id == %d", id)

        var error: NSError?

        if moc.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) == 0 {
            return nil
       }

        var logo = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
        if error != nil {
            return nil
        }

        println("--------------")
        println(logo)
        println("--------------")
        return logo?.first as? Logo
    }
```

Comment: How is the "id" property defined in the Core Data model inspector? Does the fetch request return something if you *don't* add a predicate? Is the wanted object among the results?

Comment: id is int64 property of Object entity

Comment: it returns all objects in entity

Comment: Activate Core Data SQLite debugging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306343/how-to-print-core-data-debug-values) and add the output to your question.

Comment: You should also show how you call this function and make sure you pass the ID you think you are passing.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit guessing, but the problem could be that
the `%d` format formats a C `int` value, which is a 32-bit quantity on a
32-bit device. For 64-bit integer, you should replace the predicate by

```
NSPredicate(format: "object.id == %lld", id)
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "object.id == %@", NSNumber(longLong: id))
```

Comment: @user3224534: What about the debugging that I suggested in a comment to your question?