# Core Data - why is my NSPredicate not resulting in the correct SQL query?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have tried both these     `NSPredicate`s:

```
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: “personID == %lld", id)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: “personID == %d", id)
```

I enabled SQL logging and saw this at the end of the SQL query:

```
WHERE  t0.ZPERSONID = ?
```

In variables view, `id` has a value of `Int64(156)`, but regardless of what I put in place of `id`, the resulting SQL query has `t0.ZPERSONID = ?` for its WHERE clause. Because of this, the predicate is useless and I’m getting duplicate record insertions every time. How do I get `t0.ZPERSONID = 156`?

Comment: you can check values also there in the log, but all values will be together comma separated you can put them in above query

Comment: @VarunNaharia I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you meant by that comment. What log are you referring to and where do I see these values?

Comment: @VarunNaharia The only thing SQL logging added to the console log in Xcode is that one query, of which I posted the WHERE clause. There's nothing else.

Comment: @Questioner: Set the Core Data debug level to 3 (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12306537/1187415) and then you'll see what values the SQLite query is bound to.

Comment: @MartinR That added two more lines:
`CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 2595` and the query again with this information `returned 0 rows with values: (
)`

Comment: Look at the saved `personID` and the string reprensentation resulting of `%lld", id` and compaire them.

Comment: That means that query is "WHERE  t0.ZPERSONID = 2595". – If `id` is an `Int64` then `NSPredicate(format: "personID == %lld", id)` should be correct. What does `print(predicate)` show?

Comment: @MartinR `personID == -5764607523034232269`
`id` is Int64(163) now

Comment: @MartinR I seemed to have fixed the problem. While `id` had a value of `Int64(164)`, its type was `NSNumber` (this was chosen when the `NSManagedObject` subclass was generated). I cast it to `Int64` and now the SQL query has the correct value in it. Thanks for your help. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE  t0.ZPERSONID = ?
```

is (part of) the prepared statement. To  see which values the parameters are bound to, set the Core Data debugging level to 3 (compare [How to print Core Data debug values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306343/how-to-print-core-data-debug-values/12306537#12306537)):

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
```

Also `print(predicate)` is useful to check the created predicate 
for correctness.

In your case the problem is that you pass an `NSNumber` instance
as argument, but the `%lld` format expects an `Int64`.

You can convert the `NSNumber` to an `Int64`

```
let id = NSNumber(value: Int64(156))

let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "personID == %lld", id.int64Value)
print(p1) // personID == 156
```

or even simpler, use the `%@` format instead:

```
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "personID == %@", id)
print(p2) // personID == 156
```