# Is COLLATE supported with CoreData or NSPredicate same like sql Query? If so how?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my application, I have used core data as offline persistence database.
Everything is working as expected until my client expects a bit modification in searching records.

What I have to do is if one tries to search with **e** my query should get all record which has character as **é è ê ë** ... or whatever another form of 'e' in the non-English language.

This can be achieved in SQL query by COLLATE with the column name. But not able to create NSPredicate with COLLATE, Can anyone help me on this?

My code is something like

```
let recordFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: table)
recordFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "MyItem CONTAINS[cd] 'tem' OR MyItemIndex.MyItemStyleIndex.MyItemStyle.MyItemStyle CONTAINS[cd] 'tem' OR MyItemIndex.breweryIndex.brewery CONTAINS[cd] 'tem'")
let fetchedEmployees = try context.fetch(recordFetch)
return fetchedEmployees as! Array<NSFetchRequestResult>
```

My Debug log of SQL Query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMYITEM, t0.ZMYITEMAPPEARANCEDESCRIPTION, t0.ZMYITEMAROMADESCRIPTION, t0.ZMYITEMBREWINGMETHOD, t0.ZMYITEMHISTORY, t0.ZMYITEMHOPS, t0.ZMYITEMID, t0.ZMYITEMLANGUAGEID, t0.ZMYITEMMALT, t0.ZMYITEMMOUTHFEELDESCRIPTION, t0.ZMYITEMSLOGAN, t0.ZMYITEMSUMMARY, t0.ZMYITEMTASTEDESCRIPTION, t0.ZINGREDIENTSDESCRIPTION, t0.ZISUPLOADED, t0.ZLANGUAGEID, t0.ZMYITEMINDEX, t0.ZLANGUAGE FROM ZMYITEM t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZMYITEMINDEX t1 ON t0.ZMYITEMINDEX = t1.Z_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN ZMYITEMSTYLEINDEX t2 ON t1.ZMYITEMSTYLEINDEX = t2.Z_PK LEFT OUTER JOIN ZMYITEMSTYLE t3 ON t2.Z_PK = t3.ZMYITEMSTYLEINDEX LEFT OUTER JOIN ZBREWERYINDEX t4 ON t1.ZBREWERYINDEX = t4.Z_PK JOIN ZLANGUAGE t5 ON t0.ZLANGUAGE = t5.Z_PK WHERE (( NSCoreDataStringSearch( t0.ZMYITEM, ?, 385, 0) OR  NSCoreDataStringSearch( t3.ZMYITEMSTYLE, ?, 385, 0) OR  NSCoreDataStringSearch( t4.ZBREWERY, ?, 385, 0)) AND  t5.ZLANGUAGECODE = ?) ORDER BY t1.ZCURRENTAVERAGESCORE DESC LIMIT 50
```

Yes, its working now with contains[cd]... may be some caching issue.

Thanks

Comment: you can do something like `"name==[c]"`

Comment: Ashwin bhai aa try karo [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name LIKE[c] %@", @"teste"]; OR change to **[d]** may be work karse sure nathi.

Comment: No success with any of your solution yet. My issue is not regarding the case. It's with different characters(Unicode) in diff. language...and I need all related records for the same character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the "d" option for "diacritical insensitive" comparison,
e.g.

```
NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[d] %@", givenName)
NSPredicate(format: "name ==[d] %@", givenName)
```

In addition, you might want to add the "c" option for case insensitive
search, e.g.

```
NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", givenName)
```

For more information, see
[String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

Comment: Actually, case sensitivity is not the issue... the issue with such characters like ë, if I search with ë then its working fine... but I need 'ë' even if I search with 'e'.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: Did you try it with the **d** option?

Comment: Let me try with cd by replacing my current option c

Comment: Creating predicate like MyItem CONTAINS[cd] 'tem' OR MyItemIndex.MyItemStyleIndex.MyItemStyle.MyItemStyle CONTAINS[cd] 'tem' OR MyItemIndex.breweryIndex.brewery CONTAINS[cd] 'tem'

Comment: No, None of above suggestion is working for me. tried my ways and with [c],[d], [cd]... but no success yet.

Comment: Predicate string is generated dynamically... i have added main logic only. as need predicate string for collate... Thanks

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: How is the *entity* defined and what *properties* does it have??

Comment: Bit complex relationship and huge database... but its stable and relationship added properly and working fine... only I need is searching criteria update.

Comment: I am fairly sure that it works. Without a *concrete* example (including all relevant Core Data definitions) I cannot help any further.

Comment: I'm Trying with all the suggestions of a solution... but my predicate is excluding that kind of characters records. Searching working case in sensitive but not like collate is work...Anyway Thanks for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Some web pages say like "It's worth noting that there is one additional parameter you can also pass in: "d". It stands for diacritic insensitive. So if you wanted your filter to be both case and diacritic insensitive just use:" But not working to me... don't know what can bet issue... As i can see. That records were excluded for my return array ;(

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: You can enable Core Data debugging (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306343/how-to-print-core-data-debug-values) and inspect the generated SQL query and results.

Comment: Hmmm, I have followed and read many of your answers for core data.

Comment: Pleases let me know if you find any of my mistake in the code. above query for contains[cd]. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: I don't see an obvious error, but I don't know your entities. – I would suggest that you start with a simpler request, e.g. `NSPredicate(format: "MyItem CONTAINS[cd] 'ten'")`

Comment: It works for me up to one more level... I can continue now for other changes :) So Now I accepted your Answer as it worked for me. Thank you