# CoreData - Invalid SQL (must specify a limit with an offset)

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to get the number of items that I will get if a fetch request is executed. I use the countFor of the NSManagedObject. For count and offset, there are non-negative values and also count is greater than 0. When the code is executed, app crashes with this in console.

**[error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLCountRequestContext: 0x600002990c40> , Invalid SQL (must specify a limit with an offset) with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLCountRequestContext: 0x600002990c40> , Invalid SQL (must specify a limit with an offset) with userInfo of (null)
2022-01-05 18:16:43.413899+0530 colegia[11406:83454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid SQL (must specify a limit with an offset)'**

Code:

```
 context.performAndWait {

        let request: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>.init(entityName: "ENTITY_NAME")

        
        request.fetchLimit = count
        
        request.fetchOffset = offset
           
        request.includesPropertyValues = false
                                
        do {
            announcementsCount = try context.count(for: request)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
 }
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You are using limit and offset together with a `count` request which doesn't make any sense since such request only returns one row.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, but will that cause this crash ?

Comment: Try without offset and limit set and see if to works. You should also activate Core Data debugging so you see what sql statement is executed

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ,how to activate core data specific debugging ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306343/how-to-print-core-data-debug-values

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah thank you.I will have a look at it. And as you said I tried without offset and limit and it didn't crash.