# What are the units for "Save duration" in the Core Data Saves instrument?

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode-instruments

In the XCode Instruments application there is a Core Data Saves instrument. It can show the "Save duration" for each Core Data save. What units is it using for the Save Duration? With no humanly perceptible lag time I'm seeing readings ranging from 67 to 6343.

Is this counting microseconds, something related to processor cycles, or multiples of the instrument sample time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Save duration: Duration of the save operation in microseconds.

For further info see [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-core-data-instruments-help/AbouttheCoreDataSavesInstrument/AbouttheCoreDataSavesInstrument.html).

Furthermore, if you enable the debug functionality for Core Data

> -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1

You can also see duration times within the console. In this case they are expressed in seconds. To enable it see [XCode4 and Core Data: How to enable SQL Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging).

Comment: Doh! I read that article, don't know how I missed that. Thanks.