# Why is this code raising the "CoreData: error: (19) PRIMARY KEY must be unique" error?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

This code raises the "CoreData: error: (19) PRIMARY KEY must be unique" error.
The `Day` entity has only a `when` attribute which is an `NSDate`, and a to-many relationship called `tasks`. Why this error? If a `Day` with a specific date is already stored, I fetch it, otherwise I insert it. So, for each day object, there should be a different `when` attribute. I am not sure if this is the primary key though. How to solve this ? Thank you in advance.

```
   NSMutableSet *occurrences = nil;

   occurrences = ... 
   NSMutableOrderedSet *newSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithCapacity:[occurrences count]];

   for(NSDate *current in occurrences) {

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // try to find a corresponding Day entity whose when attribute is equal to the current occurrence
        // if none is available, create it

        Day * day = [[self getDayForDate:current inManagedObjectContext:moc] retain];
        if(!day){
            day = (Day *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        }

        day.when = current;
        [day addTasksObject:aTask];

        [newSet addObject:day];

        [moc insertObject:day];
        [moc processPendingChanges];

        [day release];

        [pool release];            
    } 

- (Day *)getDayForDate:(NSDate *)aDate inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
{        
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(when == %@)", aDate];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];

    Day *theDay = nil;

    if(array && [array count] == 1){
        theDay = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return theDay;
}
```

Comment: I guess you don't need to insert a new day if you have already it (this is the case when `day` is not nil). In particular I'm referring to `[moc insertObject:day];`. Why do you it?

Comment: If you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`, that method insert the object for you when you save the moc. If you need to modify it (you have retrieved a non-nil day) modify it and save. In additon, I will do `processPendingChanges` when the loop finishes (just for performance reasons).

Comment: @Flex_Addicted, you are right. Right now the Day object is inserted unconditionally. This is probably the source of the problem. I will verify this. However, I can not save at the end of the loop, since other objects are lying around and still needs to be edited. I will let you know about.

Comment: errata corrige in first comment: *why do use it?* Then, if you cannot save, move the `processPendingChanges` at the end of the for loop. Have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, it works as expected now. Lesson learnt: never work late in the night, looking at this now it seems trivial (but it was not this night). If you recast your comments as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: + 1 for lesson learnt. I replied to your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you don't need to insert a new `Day` if you already have it (this is the case when day is not nil). In particular I'm referring to `[moc insertObject:day]`.

If you use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`, that method inserts the object for you when you save the moc. If you need to modify it (you have retrieved a non-nil day) modify it and save. In additon, I will do `processPendingChanges` when the loop finishes (just for performance reasons).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 19):

I have recently been struggling with the `CoreData: error: (19) PRIMARY KEY must be unique` error with an in-house iOS application, and thankfully discovered the solution after a day or two of research and code modifications, and I wanted to share my findings here in the hopes that they would be of help to others.

**First, a little background**

Our in-house app was never originally built with any code to update its CoreData store - instead for each app build iteration when new data was required to be displayed within the app, the CoreData SQLite backing store file was simply replaced with a new version that had been edited with a standard desktop-based SQLite editor -- that is the raw SQLite file was modified and updated as needed. While it is recognized that this approach does not take account of the "black-box" nature of CoreData, it had actually served us well with our simple app for the past few years, and the app had happily accepted the updated SQLite file with each new app build.

However, recently we undertook a major overhaul of the app, moving away from a model of updating app assets and data via Xcode and app rebuilds, to a model of obtaining new app data via a web service instead, and it was during this new development work that the `PRIMARY KEY must be unique` issue arose.

After several days of struggling to solve the issue, thinking that there must be some fault with the new CoreData entity-creation code (which had been checked and rechecked thoroughly) or some other related issue, I found through further research that I was able to enable CoreData SQL debugging for our app using Xcode (as per the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging) very helpful SO post).

When I carefully studied the SQL logs in Xcode, I could see that before each call that CoreData made to `INSERT` a new record into the SQLite backing store, that the framework queried the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table with the following query `SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?` where `?` is replaced behind the scenes with the relevant `Z_ENT` value for the relevant CoreData entity (you can see the `Z_ENT` value for each of your CoreData entities by reviewing the contents of the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table). This is when I finally understood what was happening within CoreData's black box! I then took a closer look at our app's SQLite file using the Liya app on the Mac, and I reviewed the contents of the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table, and sure enough the `Z_MAX` column values were all set to `0`. They had never been changed from their initial values when CoreData had first generated the empty SQLite backing store file for our app!

I immediately realised what was going wrong and just why CoreData had reported the primary key error as it had -- it was not in fact related to any higher-level CoreData entity object's attributes clashing somehow as initially suspected, but was indeed a lower-level error. Only now did the error make absolute sense, it had been there all along, it had just not been understood within the correct context.

As it turned out from further research, our in-house team had been successfully making direct edits to the SQLite backing store for the past few years, inserting, updating and deleting records from the various entity tables, BUT our team had never made any changes to the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table, and due to the way that our app had been utilising CoreData in a read-only fashion, this had never been an issue.

However, now that our app was trying to create and save CoreData entries back to the SQLite backing store, many of the `INSERT` queries which were being generated as a result simply failed because CoreData was unable to obtain the correct maximum primary key value from which to generate the next sequential primary key on any given table, and as such the `INSERT` query would fail with the now understandably meaningful `PRIMARY KEY must be unique` error!

**Solving the Error**

I realise that each developer may go about generating the default/initial CoreData content for their apps in various ways, however, if you have ever come across this particular error in CoreData and also struggled to find an immediately clear answer, I hope the following thoughts are of help:

- Our app's CoreData backing store was manually updated via directly editing the SQLite file (inserting, updating, and deleting records from the entity tables) - this approach had worked for a long time because of the read-only way we had been consuming this data within our app. However this approach failed to truly recognize the abstract "black box" nature of CoreData and that fact that SQLite records are not equivalent to CoreData entities, and that SQLite joins are not equivalent to CoreData relationships, and so on.
- If your app uses any kind of pre-populated CoreData store, and if you are populating the contents of your SQLite backing store in any way other than through CoreData -- make sure that if you do create new records in any of your CoreData entity tables, that you also ensure that you update the relevant record in the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table, setting the `Z_MAX` column value to the current maximum `Z_PK` value in the relevant entity table.

  For example if you have a CoreData entity called `Employee`, within your CoreData
  SQLite persistent store backing file this will be represented by a table named `ZEMPLOYEE` -
  this table will have some 'hidden' CoreData columns including `Z_PK`, `Z_ENT`,
  `Z_OPT`, etc, in addition to columns that represent your entity's
  attributes and relationships. This entity table will also have a corresponding record in the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table with a `Z_NAME` value of `Employee` - thus when you add a new record directly to the `ZEMPLOYEE` table - make sure that after you are done adding records, that you go through each entity table and copy the maximum `Z_PK` value to the `Z_MAX` column of the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table. The value you enter into `Z_MAX` should be the largest `Z_PK` value in the corresponding table; do not set `Z_MAX` to be equal to the value of `Z_PK` + 1, as this will not be what CoreData is expecting!

You can query for the maximum `Z_PK` value of any entity table with the following SQL:

```
"SELECT Z_PK FROM ZEMPLOYEE ORDER BY Z_PK DESC LIMIT 1"
```

This will give you the largest `Z_PK` value for any record in the `ZEMPLOYEE` table - obviously you should replace `ZEMPLOYEE` with the relevant table name for your app's data model.

For our app, I was able to write a simple command line script that reads the SQLite file directly, iterating through each record of the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table and updating it with the correct `Z_MAX` value. Once this was done, I was able to use this updated file as the app's persistent store backing file. Now, when I insert and save new CoreData entities, everything works as expected.

Now that our app has a way to directly request new data through a web-service we will be moving away entirely from manually editing the SQLite backing store and exclusively using the CoreData frameworks to update the data, but for times, or other apps, where such quick-and-easy data entry may be needed, I hope this answer can help out other developers and save them the time and the effort that it took me to discover this solution.

Comment: If you set Z_MAX to -1 then, on the next insert into the table, CoreData will 1) work out what the next PK should be based on what is already there and 2) update Z_MAX to the correct value for you.

Comment: From my part, I'm using SQLITE DATABASE BROWSER 2.0 which is a very simple viewer and editor for Sqlite databases. It's very simple but very effective. Thanks to @lanp. Your advice allowed me to solve this issue shortly.

Comment: From your point of view, is it possible to programmatically change the Z_MAX value to -1, by using CoreData methods or by another way? I need to make that at runtime but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Lisarien If you use the CoreData APIs to manage your data, you shouldn't need to reset Z_MAX, and relying on it may be problematic if Apple changes the API. My previous answer was the result of inheriting an app that didn't use CoreData effectively. As CoreData itself doesn't provide a method to manipulate Z_MAX, you would have to use the sqlite3 framework to perform SQL queries directly against your CoreData sqlite database. I wouldn't recommend this as a long-term strategy however, and you will need to be careful to make sure you reset the Z_MAX value before CoreData loads the sqlite file.