# Core Data and NSSortDescriptor not sorting according to third descriptor based on NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uikit

I have an NSFetchRequest that is fetching an entity called "Player" and I want the results be sorted by 3 attributes in the following order:

1. Whether the attribute called "sendingoffOffence" is nil or not
2. Whether the relationship in the entity at "team.homeMatch" is nil or not
3. I want the strings in the "number" attribute to be sorted in ascending order.

Basically, I am looking to have all players that have a red card ("sendingOffOffence" is not nil) appear at the top of the list, then have the set be ordered by whether the player is on the home team or not, and then finally get the set of players on a team in an offense group be sorted by their jersey numbers.

As such, I use the following code in my fetch request:

```
// Set the entity for the fetch request
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Player"
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.match.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"match == %@", self.match];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Sort the results

// Sort according to whether the user has a red card / sendingOffOffence
NSSortDescriptor *hasRedCard = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sendingoffOffence" ascending:NO];

// Sort according to whether the user is on the home team or not
NSSortDescriptor *isHomeTeam = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"team.homeMatch" ascending:NO];

// Sort according to the player's jersey numbers
NSSortDescriptor *number     = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[hasRedCard, isHomeTeam, number]];

// Set the amount of records to retrieve from the database
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
     initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
     managedObjectContext:self.match.managedObjectContext
     sectionNameKeyPath:nil
     cacheName:@"MatchCache"]
```

However, when I execute the above code, I get the following results:

[image: red cards sort]
[image: yellow card sort]

This sorting order is wrong because I want the following order to appear in the red card section:

- 11 - Home
- 12 - Home
- 0 - Away
- 11 - Away
- 21 - Away

And in the yellow card section:

- 1 - Home
- 2 - Home
- 99 - Home
- 1 - Away
- 31 - Away

It looks like the yellow card section sorts correctly but the red card section is showing very weird behavior that makes it appear that it is not getting sorted at all.

I am fairly stumped as to why the red card section fails to sort correctly - any thoughts? Should I just sort these objects in memory instead of relying on core data to get my preferred order?

Please be aware that this is a core data application with a SQL backed persistence store.

**UPDATE**

The following is the SQL statement that core data is using in my fetch:

```
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x11c77cd0> on entity 'SPlayer' with 
sql text 'SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK FROM ZFSMANAGEDOBJECT t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZSTEAM t1 ON 
t0.ZTEAM = t1.Z_PK WHERE ( t0.ZMATCH1 = ? AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?) ORDER BY 
t0.ZSENDINGOFFOFFENCE DESC, t1.ZHOMEMATCH DESC, t0.ZNUMBER COLLATE NSCollateFinderlike '
```

---

Comment: [Turn on SQL debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging) and make sure it's generating the SQL you expect.  You can turn up the debug level to make it log the data it's receiving in addition to the SQL it's sending.

Comment: Is your managed object context saved? Are you sure your labels are not just incorrectly displayed?

Comment: I turned on SQL debugging and added the SQL command above. I am not displaying the items incorrectly as the array in my FetchedResultsController is the thing that is not sorted correctly.

Comment: How did you implement `localizedCompare:` ?

Comment: @tilo I am using the localizedStandardCompare: method that is part of the NSString class: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line that is not being properly applied (for the RED card case):

```
NSSortDescriptor *isHomeTeam = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"team.homeMatch" ascending:NO];
```

Without seeing your data model and some of the sample data, it's hard to say why this would not be sorting properly. I would assume this would put NIL values first, then proper values next (so sorting ascending NO would do what it's doing in the YELLOW card case).

If I was in this situation, I would check my assumptions about sort order and these team.homeMatch properties. Do a test where this is the only sort description.

Then focus in on what is different with the RED/YELLOW card condition.

Comment: Thanks Jess - so it looks like when "sendingoffOffence" is NOT null, other sort descriptors fail to get applied, but they work correctly when it IS null.

Answer (score 1):

We done without NSFetchedResultsController like this check it....

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Player"
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.match.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"match == %@", self.match];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Sort the results

// Sort according to whether the user has a red card / sendingOffOffence
NSSortDescriptor *hasRedCard = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sendingoffOffence" ascending:NO];

// Sort according to whether the user is on the home team or not
NSSortDescriptor *isHomeTeam = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"team.homeMatch" ascending:NO];


[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[hasRedCard, isHomeTeam]];

// Set the amount of records to retrieve from the database
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSArray *resultArray = [self.match.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


NSSortDescriptor *number     = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:number, nil]];
```