# Core Data Entity record disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

In some iOS app written in `Objective C` and using `Core Data`, I have the following issue.
I have an entity (called myEntity) initialized with one record. I have checked, by counting the number of records, using the debugger, that it contains one record after initialization.

But I also can see this error message, right after saving the record:

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "Error while saving."

So I am not so confident that it is really saved.

Later inside the app I need this record (in myEntity), but for some unknown reason myEntity has lost its unique record, and contains nothing.

I want to locate the point where the record disappears in order to solve the problem.

Is there some kind of break point I can use for that purpose?
I have read about `Test Failure Breakpoints`, but the way to use them doesn't seem clear.

There is one more detail I need to add in order to be precise. If I close the app, before needing the record, and reopen it; then everything goes fine with no problem at all.

Comment: You can check by enabling debug mode for Core data. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging

Comment: That means your record is failed to save. You need to check your code or logic.

Comment: Right, I found my mistake, for some reason that I ignore I was setting the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption the wrong way.