# In swift, keypath not found for entity in fetched results controller with compound predicates

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

For a NSFetchedResultsController, I am trying to create a request that satisfies any 1 of 3 possible double-conditions (1 AND "Masculine") OR (2 AND "Masculine") OR (3 AND "Masculine"). 1,2,3 are stored column integers, and "Masculine" the value of a to-one relationship from a CellData entity to Gender.text (.text is indexed).

[image]

The data seems correct in CoreData. There is a column value, and PK values for Gender rows are assigned to the coreData.gender relationship attribute (see below).

BUT - I am getting an error: keypath cellData.gender.text not found in entity

I suspect it is the way I am creating my Predicates or Compound Predicates as this is new to me.

Initially, cellData.gender.text predicates are defined with a value matching an existing value in DB:

```
var col0GenderPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cellData.gender.text == %@", "Masculine")
var col2GenderPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cellData.gender.text == %@", "Masculine")
var col3GenderPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "cellData.gender.text == %@", "Masculine")
```

In the fetched results controller, predicates are:
1) Defined for cellData.column values.
2) Compounded into corresponding pairs of column AND cellData.gender.text values.
3) Further compounded as an OR compound predicate.

```
@objc private func loadSavedData()
{
    if fetchedResultsController == nil
    {
        print("creating fetchresultsController")
        let request = CellData.createFetchRequest()    
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder", ascending: true)    // sort by name
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]     
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                              managedObjectContext: container.viewContext,
                                                              sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                              cacheName: nil) as? NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>

// 1)
        let column0Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "column == %ld", 1)
        let column2Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "column == %ld", 3)
        let column3Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "column == %ld", 4)

// 2)   
        let col0AndGenderPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and,
                                                         subpredicates: [column0Predicate, col0GenderPredicate])
        let col2AndGenderPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and,
                                                                 subpredicates: [column2Predicate, col2GenderPredicate])
        let col3AndGenderPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and,
                                                         subpredicates: [column3Predicate, col3GenderPredicate])

// 3)
        let columnAndGenderPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [col0AndGenderPredicate, col2AndGenderPredicate, col3AndGenderPredicate])

        fetchedResultsController?.fetchRequest.predicate = columnAndGenderPredicate
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    }

    do { try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch() }
    catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

Then I get an error:
error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , keypath cellData.gender.text not found in entity  with userInfo of (null)

But cellData.gender is in CoreData:
[image]

And gender.text is also there:
[image]

Other discussions suggest an error with FetchedResultsController, but it was working until I started chaining the Predicates, and I can't find anything highlighting the problem there or anything to try.

Comment: Tip: [Xcode 4 and Core Data: How to enable SQL Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode-4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your NSFetchedResultsController to request data from `CellData` so then the keypath should be `gender.text` only

```
 var col0GenderPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "gender.text == %@", "Masculine")
```

Also, compared to what you write and the images it looks like you have a typo here

```
 let column0Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "column == %ld", 0)
```

shouldn't it be 1 rather than 0 or is the text in the question wrong?

Comment: gosh! I don't know why I thought it would be different. Relationships scare me. I corrected the column typo in the question - thx. On to the next breakpoint!